# Is there a way to control the roomba i7 actuators and sensors?

Tags: roomba, programming-languages

I would like to write my own program for controlling sensors and actuators of Roomba i7. For previous robots it was possible with some minor hacks.
Is there a way to flash an opensource firmware or a library to directly control the robot's behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no way for a user to control the Roomba i7.  Instead, you should use the [Create 3](https://edu.irobot.com/what-we-offer/create3).

Disclaimer: I work at iRobot where I am developing the next generation of consumer robots. However, my postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.